# Parsing data to Objective-C with XML or JSON with Python / Django backend

Tags: python, objective-c, xml, django, json

Ok all! I have a question for you...Currently looking at building an Iphone app with Objective-C and were going to be using Python / Django as the back-end as the website is already built. Meaning all the content is already stored in the database. Were going to use an app called tastypie as our API which can either pull then data into a JSON format or XML.

However I want to know which is going to be the best for my needs, either JSON or XML? The data that is going to be pulled is a directory list which will display a map within each property. Then a page which will display a load of recipes.

If you could give your thoughts on which you think is going to be the best to use from JSON or XML, would be awesome! :)

If you need to know any more information, please let me know.

Thanks,

Josh

Comment: Objective C is perfectly good at parsing both XML and JSON, and so is Python, so that's not an issue. The difference is that XML has a lot more structure than JSON. If you don't need any structure that you can't render directly in JSON, use JSON. Sometimes, even if you do need more structure, it's worth rendering it indirectly in JSON, or leaving it implicit. Otherwise, use XML. Without knowing exactly what your documents have in them and how it's structured, nobody can give you a firm recommendation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really depends on the data you need to represent.

If you need to represent programming language objects, JSON is probably you best choice, being more lightweight and human-readable than XML.

If you need to represent a complex data structure with its custom schema, you will probably want to give XML a shot.

That being said, Objective-C provides both XML and JSON parsers.